# ecommerce dynamic breadcrumb best practice - How Do you do yours?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, breadcrumbs

I am looking for a best practice to provide users of my ecommerce website with a breadcrumb trail.

Current Site Setup:

ASp.net 3.5
SQL express 2005 DB

DB Table Setup:

[Category] - ID, parentid, name etc
[Product] - ID catID name

Should i use a sqlsitemap provider and everytime i save a product add it to the Sitemap table ?

is there a more dynamic way to achieve the desired result ?

looking for your thoughts / ideas to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps drop the implementation technology tags, and go with "html". You customer experience should not depend on the server technology.

Answer (score 0):

There is this [artictle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163657.aspx) which may help with creating the sql provider that you can use with the default breadcrumb in asp.net. It also has sql caching for a speadier response too.